# what is the rationale for this order in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

trying to understand what is going on here with a python dictionary. I am trying to return a list of the items using dic.values(). However, I can't figure out the order that items are supposed to be returned in.

For example:

```
dic = {'a':10, 'b':9, 'c':11, 'd':12}
>>> dic.values()
[10, 11, 9, 12]
```

Returns not one of the logical options of sorting by keys or sorting by items, but something else entirely

Comment: If there is a duplicate, you might want to mention it. Also, some people are picky about wording. I am not one of them.

Comment: it has been marked as a duplicate by martijn. i was looking at that

Comment: Ah, I refreshed the page just now. I think the other question was phrased in a less assertive way.

Comment: Maintaining order is antithetical to fast lookups. Highly illogical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "logical" ordering in a Python set. It is normally printed by order of hash which is supposed to be arbitrary.

Comment: `s/random/arbitrary/`, but have my +1.

Comment: The only guarantee (which is useful) is that if you call `keys` and `values` without modifying the dict in between, the value in a given position will correspond with the key in the same position.

Comment: ok, so if I were to add another key to the dictionary, the order of existing elements would be preserved and the key would simply be inserted into some implementation dependent location?

Comment: @user3684792, Based on the linked answer in the duplicate question, yes.